2018 Annual Support Proposals
It's time to divide up our Annual Support from TLG as discussed here.
Here are the sets that we were given:
Ideas: Fishing Store (21310), Women of NASA (21312)
Architecture: Sydney (21032), Shanghai (21039)
Brick Headz: Rey, Kylo, Aquaman, Wonder Woman, Flash
Technic: 42074, 42077
Creator: 31072, 31075, 31080, 31074
Classic: 10712, 10715

I will be accepting proposals for using these sets for Bricks.SE purposes here until June 8th.
Users submitting proposals must meet the following requirements:

You must be in good standing with Bricks.SE and must have earned at least 125 rep in 2018 or 1k rep total.
Shipping costs will be paid by you to me via PayPal. I'll ship USPS and invoice you the actual shipping cost including anything I spend on shipping materials.
Sets may never be resold or given to non-members. This is a TLG requirement. Sets will be shipped unboxed to further discourage resale.
The requested set(s) and/or elements need to be prominently featured in at least one question by you. Your question(s) should be part of the request to receive your set(s). The question will likely be self-answered by you and should be tagged as annual-support. Alternatively, I'm open to other non-Q&A creative uses of these sets as well (social media campaigns, etc).
Depending on the number of proposals we have, I may be including some of the "leftover" sets in your shipment. These will not be required to be used directly for answering questions, but they certainly could be.

I'm very open to input from anyone on this process. However, because I have to report back to TLG how these sets were used, final decisions over who gets what will be at my sole discretion.

Hmm I'm a little worried if the shipping costs would add up depending on the size of the set (not that I'm interested in any of the bigger sets), as well as where I live (Singapore). I hear shipping sets unboxed reduces that a bit, is that true? Also, if costs can only be ascertained by preparing the shipment, I'm not sure if I'll be prepared for it.

Shipping would likely be quite expensive to Singapore, unfortunately. USPS has a shipping cost calculator if that is helpful: https://postcalc.usps.com/

Thanks, sadly it does look like it'd cost as much if not more to get a set like 31080 or 10715 shipped than it would to just buy it locally (and boxed) :(

Have all the sets been sent out?

@Ambo100 They've all been sent out, except for the handful of Creator and Classic sets that I'm using.

@jncraton I have finally posted my annual support question and given an answer as well. Apologies for the delay.

I would like a chance to review 21310 Old Fishing Store and answer the question:

How big is the color inconsistency problem of Sand Green colored LEGO bricks?

Sand Green has historically been a color with significant color shade differences, and since Old Fishing Store has a lot of these bricks and tiles, it will be a good set to review this.

I like that. Would I be correct in assuming that you have older sand green parts hanging around so that you can compare consistency over time as well as within a single large set?

My LEGO collection only goes a few years back, but I will try. I can also ask some local LUG members to assist me if needed.

No worries if that doesn't work out. I was mostly just curious.

I'd like to move forward with sending this out to you. Please send an email to my SE username at gmail with your shipping details.

Done and done...

I have an idea for 42077 Rally Car, which I think LEGO would appreciate.

How can I motorize 42077 Rally Car with LEGO Power Functions?
The Rally Car set looks really nice, and even has a built-in steering system which can be controlled by a gear on the top. There's also a fair bit of extra room inside, is there a way to add Power Functions elements to make it remote controlled?

And then the answer would be instructions on how to rebuild the set to accommodate adding Power Functions, which I'm confident can be done fairly easily (I'm thinking servo and L motor would do nicely).
I have lots of Power Functions elements on hand, and would definitely be willing to write both the question and answer, and I could probably come up with some other Q&A's while at it. I also think this could potentially be beneficial to LEGO as it advertises a way to use both this set and their Power Functions elements (and a reason to buy them).
For LEGO's benefit, I can also post instructions to social media.
UPDATE: Q&A posted.

I'd like to move forward with sending this out to you. Please send an email to my SE username at gmail with your shipping details.

I think I could do something with the brickheadz

Can two or more Brick Headz be combined to create a figure on a larger scale that is similar to Brick Headz or at least is humanoid in appearance?

I don't have any of the donated brick headz but have about a dozen of the older ones, I have also the Brick Me set to add pieces.
I would answer something like "Yes, I combined Brick Headz X and Y and pieces of Z to get: " followed with a picture of the result. If the question/answer is well received I would attempt instructions as a follow up...

I'll happily send all of the Brick Headz to you. Please send an email to my SE username at gmail with your shipping details.

I'd like to hang on to a few of the Classic and Creator sets. I'm assuming that these will be a bit less popular among our AFOL userbase.
I don't have precise questions in mind since I haven't looked at the parts yet, but I'd like to do something along the lines of:

What are some uses for {part}?

I like to make alternate models, and these themes are usually brilliant for that. I'd likely post many alternate builds to Rebrickable and hopefully that experience would give me ideas for good building or part identification questions along the lines of this or this.

Nah I just don't meet the requirements since I haven't been active in the past year.

@BoltClock I've updated the requirements to be either 125 rep in 2018 (so we can include new and active users) or 1k total rep (so that we can include folks like you who have contributed a lot in the past but haven't been active recently). The goal of these requirements is to prevent people from creating an account just for the purpose of getting a free set. :) I don't want to exclude legitimate participants.

I'm reading this while in a LEGO Certified Store checking out the new stuff... I gotta get home stat.
