2020 Q3 Activity Support Proposals
There's been some discussion previously about how to make use of our quarterly Activity Support provided by TLG. Here's an excerpt regarding LEGO Online Community Activity Support for those who may not be familiar:

The purpose of RLFM/RLOC Activity Support is to provide Recognized
LEGO Fan Media (RLFM) and Recognized LEGO Online Communities (RLOC)
the opportunity to do online activities and reviews outside of the
marketing offerings of the LEGO Group. Any use of the support provided
is to be within the LEGO® Brand Values and requires the RLFM/RLOC to
clearly indicate that the products are provided by the LEGO® Group.
Examples of online activities

Reviews of LEGO sets or themes
Competitions where LEGO sets are used for inspiration and/or prizes
Live builds
Raffles
Token of appreciation to community members

The level of support One request can include products worth no more
than: 500 EUR
Please use your local Shop@Home as reference for products availability
and German Shop@Home for prices before you fill up the order document.
If you don´t have a local Shop@Home, please use German Shop@Home for
prices and assortment availability as reference. Discounted product
prices cannot be used for reference, it must be the full price.
Please note that products NOT available on your local Shop@Home cannot
be ordered. If you order a product not available, it won´t be
replaced. We also recommend you to not request products out of stock
or in backlog as we cannot ensure delivery.

If there is interest, I'd like to split up our Q3 Activity Support between a few members to create engaging and useful content for our community. This would be similar to what we did with our 2018 Annual Support, except we have control over which sets to select.
We can ship to up to 5 different addresses, and request up to 500 EUR of sets, so keep that in mind if you create a proposal. Proposals up to 100 EUR should be easy to work in, but more than that will need stronger justification, as you may be eating into funds that could have been allocated to another member.
I will be accepting proposals here until June 30th. I'm very open to input from anyone on this process. However, because I have to report back to TLG how these sets were used, final decisions over what is approved will be at my discretion. Important factors for me will be community feedback for a users proposal (via comments and votes here), as well as the quality of content that a user generally creates.
Users submitting proposals must meet the following requirements:

You must have earned at least 200 rep in 2020 or 1k rep total.
You may not resell these sets. This is a TLG requirement.
The requested set(s) need to be prominently featured in at least one question. Your question(s) should be part of the proposal to receive your set(s). The question will likely be self-answered by you and should be tagged as activity-support. Alternatively, I'm open to other non-Q&A creative uses of these sets as well (social media campaigns, etc) as long as they serve the core purpose of our community.
You must be committed to completing your proposed work within 2 weeks of receiving your sets.

If inspiration is helpful, here's an example from one of our users who created some excellent content using support from TLG:
How can I motorize 42077 Technic Rally Car with LEGO Power Functions?
Update:
We're moving forward with these three proposals.

I know this community is US based, so I have to ask if this is limited to US only?

@Alex Great question. This is not US only. Most of the world should be fine, with the exception of countries where it wouldn't be legal for TLG to ship to due to sanctions or other legal concerns.

This is great! My interests are all in tinkering with spike-prime (+sensors) which I think are a bit out of the price range. Although I'd love to know how they can interact with each other over BTLE for larger systems.

I'd like to explore the internals, functionality, and potential hackability of the new Mario intelligent brick:

I would perform a teardown via a self-answered Q&A question covering the internals of this element.
If there are funds available, it would also be helpful to get a few of the Power Up Packs to determine how they interact with Mario.
Possible questions:

What is inside the new Mario intelligent brick?
How does the Mario intelligent brick sense and interact with its environment?
What sensors are included in the Mario intelligent brick?

Requested sets:

71360 Mario Starter Course (60 EUR)


Proposal Completed
'How does the LEGO Super Mario figure know which power up is attached?'
'Does the Mario Starter Course require a smart device?'

How the Mario brick works is certainly a question I might ask, because I really wonder how it can detect what it stomps on and if there are anti-cheats (if necessary) to prevent from continuously stomping on the same block over and over (and oher problems), but now that you've mentioned that question I'm afraid you're gonna beat me to it and ask the question yourself.

I've been thinking it would be cool to try to make a working LEGO glider using the sails in the 42105 Catamaran for wings.

Unfortunately they made the sails 2 different sizes, so I would need 2 copies of the set.

I could probably also do a question on a motorized speedboat.
Possible questions:

Can I make a glider out of the large sail pieces in the 42105 Catamaran Technic set?
Can I motorize the 42105 Catamaran Technic set?

Requested sets:

42105 Catamaran 38,98€ * 2 = 77.96€


Proposal Completed
'Motorized speedboat from Technic Catamaran alternate model?'

This looks great, and I'm happy to move forward with this. I've reached out via email with more details.

I would like to do an analysis of the differences between the new front fork suspension of 42107 Ducati Panigale V4 R and the existing lego shock absorbers (part 731c06). I might also be able to review characteristics of other shock absorbers produced by LEGO over the years.
Set cost: $60-$70 (US Price not yet confirmed)


Proposal Completed
'How do the various LEGO springs compare?'

And I promise to adhere to the timeline this year :)

Wait, what timeline?

See point 4 in the original post. My post from the last time we ran this was several months late :)
